# Unreadable: bootstrap-sprockets only after git merge

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I'm new to RoR and going through Hartl's Rails Tutorial.  After completing Chapter 5.4, all tests pass:

```
6 tests, 14 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Immediately afterwards, I continue to [Chapter 5.5 instructions](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/filling_in_the_layout#sec-layout_conclusion):

```
$ git add -A
$ git commit -m "Finish layout and routes"
$ git checkout master
$ git merge filling-in-layout
$ rails test
```

But now the tests return:

```
6 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 6 errors, 0 skips
```

With all errors containing:

```
ActionView::Template::Error: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-sprockets.
```

Also I'm running this on Cloud9 IDE
What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try running `bundle install` in your master branch folder as I can see that you only installed it in this filling-in-layout branch.

Comment: I got it to work but unclear exactly what the problem was.  Ran `bundle install` from master.  Ran server again.  FAIL.  Noticed test result comment mentioning _/home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/db/schema.rb doesn't exist yet. Run `rails db:migrate` to create it_ so I did that, ran server again.  FAIL.  Noticed I had rails twice in gemfile so I deleted one (even though they were the same version).  Ran `bundle install` and server again.  Pass!  Strange that tutorial didn't mention running `bundle install` in master (or maybe I missed it).  Thanks for your help  @mayorsanmayor